# How can I use Spark to tokenize remote documents where I store only the URL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, web-scraping

I'm a Spark newbie just reading a few books. Is it possible to tokenize remote documents with only their url? For example would there be a may to modify this script (taken from [this blog post](http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/06/12/tutorial-how-to-build-a-tokenizer-in-spark-and-scala/)):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object TokenizerApp {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val logFile = "src/data/sample.txt" // Should be some file on your system
 val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Tokenizer App", "/path/to/spark-0.9.1-incubating",
 List("target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
 val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
 val tokens = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
 val termFrequency = tokens.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
 termFrequency.collect.map(tf => println("Term, Frequency: " + tf))
 tokens.saveAsTextFile("src/data/tokens")
 termFrequency.saveAsTextFile("src/data/term_frequency")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to tokenize remote documents with only their url?

Sure, it is possible. First choose [your favorite HTTP library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11719373/1560062). Next write a small wrapper which takes url and returns related content:

```
def getContent(url: String): String = ???
```

Next create a RDD of urls:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val urls: RDD[String] = ???
```

Map over it using helper function and cache:

```
val contents: RDD[(String, String)] = urls.map(url => (url, getContent(url)))
contents.cache
```

Convert to a `DataFrame` so we can use built-in tokenizer:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df: DataFrame = contents.toDF("url", "text")
```

Create tokenizer and tokenize:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("tokens")
```

Tokenize:

```
val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)
```

Seriously though, don't. Using Spark for a job like this is a really bad idea for more or less the same reason why it [doesn't make sense to run Spark job only for side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555392/1560062).

If you want to utilize Spark in a web scraping pipeline you can either use **scraper** as an input stream source in [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) (it is probably an overkill) or simply collect data to a persistent storage and process with Spark afterwards.